# @ at the beginning of EditText value

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I tried to hard code a string starts with `@` as the value for `android:text` attribute, eclipse says

`error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@dmin123').`

how can I avoid this?

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/password_input" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:password="true" android:text="@dmin123"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to show @ in your edit text :

android:text="\@dmin123"

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape @ symbol. try this: `android:text="\@dmin123"`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```
android:text="\@dmin123"/>
```

you need to add forward '/' before the '@' character. Just like Escape Sequence in C Language.
I have tried it in my code & it is working fine. Showing me Command with @ in text.